# Cron Ubuntu does not fire ruby method

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, cron

crontab -l gives me this

```
0,2,4,6,8,10 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/ruben/Monitoring ; script/rails runner Ping.check_pings'
```

Why does  this not work?
If i try "cd /home/ruben/Monitoring ; script/rails runner Ping.check_pings" in the command line it works. I have also tried it with "&&" as ";"

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be related to PATH, or to some other environment variable (like GEM_HOME), that is defined properly in your command-line environment, but not in cron's environment.

Answer (score 0):

crontab doesn't run with the enviroment of the user, rather it creates it's own slimmed down enviroment. This includes very small PATH - /usr/bin:/usr/sbin:. and some other variables. See more here - http://adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference

Easiest solution is to add '. ~/.profile' before you run rails, or to fix path in some other way.

BTW, before you try to add PATH=/my/path/here;$PATH into crontab - that syntax (variable expansion) is not allowed either